# Installing mongodb on solaris -- bin/mongod: cannot execute binary file

Tags: mongodb, sunos

I am trying to install the latest mongodb on SUN OS 5.9 using package from http://www.mongodb.org/downloads.

After I unzip the package on solaris, I get the following error when I run the following

```
bin/mongod --help

bin/mongod: cannot execute binary file
```

Is there a way to fix this issue with out building the package from the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a SPARC based Solaris machine?  Because of its use of Little Endian in data storage, MongoDB does not currently work on Big Endian processors such as SPARC And PowerPC.

MongoDB will work on Solaris but only Solaris for Intel.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks